# How do I make mailto subject and body work in gmail etc?

Tags: html, mailto

Good afternoon,

I have a site with a mailto link used to email my mothers business, pretty standard stuff

I recently tried adding some other bits to get a standard subject and body, which works find when I use outlook (on my work PC) but doesn't work if I use my home PC which automatically opens gmail:

The code I have for the mailto is:

```
<a href="mailto:childminding.butterflies@gmail.com
&subject=Childminding%20query
&body=Dear%20Jo,%0A%0AYour%20message%20here%0A%0ARegards,%0A%0AName:%0AEmail:%0APhone:%0A" 
style="text-align:center;">childminding.butterflies@gmail.com</a><br /><br />
```

(it is all on one line, but that makes it very tedious to read on here)

As I said, it works fine when the computer is forced to automatically open outlook, but not so much for gmail, is there a different method that would make it better for both?

Result in gmail:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/6L7bCaD.png]

Comment: try a ? instead of the first ampersand
`&subject -> ?subject`

Comment: [SUCCESS](http://i.imgur.com/PNDAeB5.png)
I knew it'd be something simple, thanks very much

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As in the comment above, changing the ampersand into a question mark:

```
a href="mailto:childminding.butterflies@gmail.com
?subject=Childminding%20query
&body=Dear%20Jo,%0A%0AYour%20message%20here%0A%0ARegards,%0A%0AName:%0AEmail:%0APhone:%0A" 
style="text-align:center;">childminding.butterflies@gmail.com</a><br /><br />
```

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: hi, I have added above code but gmail not supporting it : Screenshot : http://prntscr.com/k1ueud