# in my html code after hitting submit it doesn't do anything i want it to take me to gmail

Tags: html, forms

```
   <form action="Gmailto:fictionalgmail@gmail.com" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
        <label>Your Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="YourName" value=""><br>
        <label>Your Email:</label>
        <input type="email" name="YourEmail" value=""><br>
        <label>Your Message:</label> <br>
        <textarea name="Message" id="YourMessage" cols="31" rows="7"></textarea>
        <br><input type="submit">
    </form>
```

i tried channging the email, security and all that stuff

Comment: it's `mailto:..` not `gmailto:`, and which email client opens depends on the user's settings, you can only call for opening a mail client, it can be gmail or whatever the user has set on their system.

Answer (score 2):

The [`mailto:` url scheme](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2368.txt) is a generic email scheme, not one specific to GMail. There isn't a URL scheme specific to GMail. There is no `g` at the front of it.

The browser needs to know about the email client you are using for them to work, and since GMail is a web app and not local software, it can't register itself at the OS level, so end users [need to configure their browser](https://usdkb.sandiego.edu/s/article/How-to-Open-Mailto-Links-in-Gmail) to use mailto URLs with GMail.

`mailto:` URLs are [notoriously unreliable as the value of a form `action`](http://isolani.co.uk/articles/mailto.html) so you should avoid them anyway.

---

If you want to handle form data, then use server side programming. It's much more reliable and gives you control over the UX.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that needs to be fixed in your code is 'Gmailto'
There is nothing as Gmailto in html. Instead you have to select '**mailto**'. So that when you click submit you will be redirected to your computer's emailing software as you requested. From there you can select your gmail account to continue.

Answer (score -1):

You have a typo in the `action`, it's `mailto:`, not `Gmailto:`

Your overall code is correct, except for where you are doing a `POST` request, email clients will often expect certain format of query parameter which is done by using `GET` method. Check this for reference -
https://stackoverflow.com/a/21046049/1391805

Comment: Using a POST with enctype text/plain is the usual way to handle form data with the mailto scheme. The answer you reference is about a link, not a form.